# File ownership under "Program Files" in Windows

Tags: windows, permissions

We are creating an application that updates it's files under Program Files - we've run into some permission errors and were starting to wonder who should be owner of files - the "SYSTEM" user or the one that installed the software? After inspecting the "Program Files" folder we see that some software binaries have the user as owner, some "SYSTEM". We are failing to overwrite some files and the only weird thing seems to be that the owner of our updater binary is the "SYSTEM" user.

Comment: In almost all cases, it makes no difference who the owner is, only what the permissions are.

Answer (score 0):

Is always better to install apps that needs write permissions in a folder under C: or you can look at ntfs permissions on that folder and add your users.